# Using sed to replace multi-line strings in apache2.conf file

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2, sed

As part of my Bash server setup script, I am trying to lock down the default apache www website.

I want to convert this:

```
<Directory /var/www>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

To this:

```
<Directory /var/www>
      Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI
```

Since `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` is mentioned multiple times in the file, I need the search and replace to include the previous line.

I've tried the below `sed` command, using backslash to escape slashes, but it doesn't replace anything:

```
cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf | sed 's/[<Directory \/var\/www\/>]\n   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks/[<Directory \/var\/www\/>]\n     Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI/;P;D'
```

I've tried putting things inside quotes and square brackets. The command also doesn't seem to like the tabs.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` by default operates on each line separately, thus you cannot use `\n`. If you want to operate on multiple lines, you can use the `-z` flag, which separates the lines by NUL characters and allows the use of `\n`.

Also, you don't have to pipe `cat`'s output to `sed`, since `sed` can read files by itself.

Furthermore, it is not mandatory to use `/` as delimiter in your `sed` command, as `sed` accepts other delimiters too. Using a different delimiter in your case has the benefit of not having to escape every `/` using a backslash (`\`).

So the command you need to run is:

```bsh
sed -z 's|<Directory /var/www>\n\tOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks|<Directory /var/www>\n\tOptions -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI|' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Notice that in the above command I used `\t` as a tab character. However, not all versions of `sed` accept `\t` as a tab character. If the above command does not work for you, you can replace `\t` by a literal tab in your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or use another method from this Stack Overflow question: [Why is sed not recognizing \t as a tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/why-is-sed-not-recognizing-t-as-a-tab)

Comment: That worked great and thanks for the extra information.  I almost replied saying it didn't work until I realised I had left off a backslash after the www in my information.  Using a different delimiter certainly makes things look clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to need the *search* to include the preceding line, but not the replace. So you could search for the first line of the pattern, then use the `n` command to load the **n**ext line, which you can then process in the usual way either using **s**ubstitute

```
sed '\:<Directory /var/www>:{
     n
     s/Options Indexes FollowSymLinks/Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI/
  }' file
```

or by **c**hanging the whole line

```
sed '\:<Directory /var/www>:{
     n
     c\      Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI
  }' file
```

Comment: Your answer also worked great and if I could tick both of you I would, sorry about that.